# Keyboard shortcut to switch between split terminal tab in PyCharm?

Tags: terminal, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

I can split a terminal window in two by right clicking it and just pressing split vertically. However, I can't find a shortcut to switch between these two views.

[image: Image of Keymap in Settings]

Wondering if anyone has found a work-around for this. Sort of a pain to have to click between the two views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to set the keyboard shortcut in `Settings` `>` `Keymap`.

The name of the shortcuts will be `Goto Next Splitter` and `Goto Previous Splitter`.

[image: Image of Goto Previous Next Splitter in Settings Keymap]